# CSS Table Cell Transparency

Tags: html, css, web, html-table

Fairly new to web design and I'm trying to make a transparent table cell.

I have a nice textured image as my body background and I want my table to have a white background apart from an empty cell on the top left, which I want to be completely invisible.

I have tried #id-ing the empty cell and setting the background colour to transparent but it is just being set to white. I have set my table background to white in my table selector but I thought my id selector would have over ridden this.

I have also tried setting the textured background image on the cell as well to make it appear transparent but it just stands out like a sore thumb.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
#my-invisible-cell { opacity: 0; }
```

or

```
#my-invisible-cell { visibility: hidden; }
```

if the problem is still there, probably there is something wrong in the table; in that case, try this:

```
<style>
table {
    background: transparent !important;
}

.white-cells {
    background: white;
}
</style>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="white-cells">White cell</td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="white-cells">White cell</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried #id-ing the empty cell and setting the background colour to transparent but it is just being set to white. I have set my table background to white in my table selector but I thought my id selector would have over ridden this.

They are different elements. The id selector doesn't override it because it matches a different element.

The table cell **is** transparent. The table itself is white. You can see through the transparent background of the table cell to the white background of the table behind it.

If you want to see the background of the body element, then you must set the background of the table transparent too. Possibly you want to set the background of every *other* cell to white.